# Dimensions of ImageMarker

Tags: vuforia

I am new to Vuforia SDK. I have an image which acts as a target. I want to place this image on to the Imagemarker. In real time the size of the Imagemarker varies. Is there any method where I can get the width and height of the Imagemarker so that the target image fits exactly on the Imagemarker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.
While placing the Image on the Image Marker to the relative size you want it to be, and when you run it you'll see that the size of the image will be relative to the Marker you've placed it on.

Comment: @RJJ- Thank you and I want my target image to fit exactly(occupy whole imagemarker) on to the imagemarker. To do this I think I need height and width of the imagemarker?

Comment: Yeah @ShashankSegu, basically all you have to do is adjust the height and width of the image so that it fits the marker's dimensions in your program, and once you test it out, whatever the dimension of the marker, the image will also change to fit it as per the markers size. Hope you're getting me :)

Comment: @RJJ-I got your point and I totally agree with you. Thank you

Comment: @ShashankSegu, you're very welcome. Please feel free to mark this as the correct answer for others to see :)

Comment: Augmented Jacob - I am able to get the image onto the targetmarker. But the problem is the image does not fits into the marker unless the camera is focussed onto the targetmarker. I mean to say that initially the image will be somewhat 70 degrees rotated about z axis upon focussing the targetmarker image fits onto the marker. I am struck and not able to move forward. Do you want code to analyze this? Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you saying the furthur away you go, it stays the same size as it was when you were close up?

Comment: No. It is not aout the size of the image, it is about the orientation of the image(pose). Initially the image will be 70 degrees rotated about the z axis. I should focus my camera onto the target device for some time and then it vl fit properly onto the targetmarker.

Comment: I've noticed you said target device. If your image is on a screen (computer/phone) then it will be glitchy.

Comment: Sorry Augmented Jacob. Instead of TargetManager I wrote TargetDevice. I have got the values for projection matrix. The values when the image is fitting properly is very different from the values when the image is not fitting onto the targertmanager.

Comment: Hmm, this problem seems to be different from the above question. I suggest you post it as a separate question on SO. Someone else might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not specify if you are using the `Unity` or native APIs I will assume you are using `Unity`.

This is how you would go about it using the `Vuforia` API, placing this in a script attached to your `ImageTarget` GameObject.

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    Vuforia.ImageTarget img = GetComponent<Vuforia.ImageTargetBehaviour>().ImageTarget;
    // This is rounded of in the console display, 
    // so individual components are printed afterwards
    Debug.Log(img.GetSize());

    Debug.Log(img.GetSize().x);
    Debug.Log(img.GetSize().y);
    Debug.Log(img.GetSize().z);
}
```

Alternatively you can directly use the `Bounds` of the renderer.

```
void Start()
{
    Renderer r = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    Debug.Log(r.bounds.size.x);
    Debug.Log(r.bounds.size.y);
    Debug.Log(r.bounds.size.z);
}
```

Needless to say this is just a quick solution, depending on the situation you might want to use this at runtime dynamically create content.